# Google Cloud Monitoring: Add an alert if Publish succeeds and subscribe fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to add an alert on Google Cloud Monitoring such that, for a given topic and a subscription, I want to know if a topic is being published then subscriptions are not being acknowledged at the same or similar rate for a given time frame.

How do we achieve that using Alerts in Google Cloud Monitoring or StackDriver?

I have tried an approach where I have 2 conditions to satisfy:

1. If publish operations > 0.016/sec for 2 minutes (meaning atleast one
   publish per minute)
2. If subscribe acknowledgments < 0.001/sec for 2 minutes (If no subscribe acknowledgements happening in 2 minutes)

Then, alert.

Whats happening here is, during low load, if there are no publishes happening say for a span of 3 minutes and a publish happens, both conditions 1 and 2 are set to be true and devs are alerted about this as failure.

So, what is the right way of designing such alerts?

If my approach is close to what I want, the next questions that come to my mind are,

1. Is there a way to say count your two minutes from the instance where
   the publish happens to see if acknowledgement condition is
   satisfying or not.
2. Or, is there a way to make the alert to wait for 2-3 minutes to see if the incident resolves, and then send an alert to devs.
3. Or, is there a way we can count the occurances of these conditions satisfying and then alert only if the occurances are more than 5 or 10 in a span of 15 minutes or something like that.

Sorry for the long post. But, any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to calculate frequency for tasks a time window of 2-3 minutes is used. So if you had 0 tasks for 2 minutes or longer this issue recurs. This is described in documentation about [partial metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/#partial-metric-data). Also, there are workarounds inside this link.

You can try creating your own [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/#partial-metric-data).